Background modelContext do not get updated from changes in the main modelContext
If my app has a new to update my SwiftData database in the background (say after a network call), based on my understanding the only legit way to do this is to use 2 modelContexts (one via ModelActor).
But if so, consider the background modelContext to be created like this:
@ModelActor
actor PlanModelActor {
    init(container: ModelContainer) {
        modelContainer = container
        let context = ModelContext(container)
        context.autosaveEnabled = false
        modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: context)
    }
}

this actor does not seem to receive updates made from the main modelContext such as this:
struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    ...
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
}

Interestingly, it works the other way around (not sure why). Changes made by the background context is automatically refreshed by @Query.
So is this a bug or intended? And if intended how do I tell the background modelContext to refresh the data straight from the database?

It cannot reproduce "Interestingly, it works the other way around". The other way around doesn't get updates either. You need to save() first before updates are received. Or you can enable autosave on the model actor's context.

"...this actor does not seem to receive updates...", yes it does but you need to manually load them since there is nothing like a @Query you can use in an actor

And on iOS 18.1 the view (@Query) gets properly updated when I create a new object using the actor.

You might be hitting the SwiftData bug addressed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78822624/719690. Changes made by a ModelActor were not visible to MainActor. The hack/workaround is to listen for the context save notification and save that Date as @State in your view.
